# Including fonts in Seaside

Tags: fonts, smalltalk, pharo, seaside

Is it possible to enclose a font file in a Seaside application so that the client renders the website using that one instead of the ones in their system?

If so, how would one do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more a question about CSS and using `@font-face`; see [this article](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/beautiful-fonts-with-font-face/), for instance.

About the Seaside side of things, the font is just a static file, so [the usual ways apply](http://book.seaside.st/book/in-action/serving-files); for instance, you could [include it in a file library](http://book.seaside.st/book/in-action/serving-files/filelibraries) and possibly as a static file served by the front-end http server for performance.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for miss-tagging it! I just didn't know you could specify the font file URL right in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You start by making sure you have the right license for the font. Most ones you get with your computer or software cannot be distributed like this without additional licensing agreements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is not a Seaside issue but a CSS one. 
In addition with Damien answer, you might want to try google fonts: http://code.google.com/webfonts

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with the others. This is not a Seaside issue, this is an overall web design/ web typography issue.

I recommend some web searches on web fonts and web typography, in general. At the moment, the general consensus among web designers is -- either stick to web safe fonts, or use an external font library such as:

- [Google WebFonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) or
- [TypeKit](https://typekit.com/)